# jQuery RadioButton index

Tags: jquery, indexing, radio-button

How to get checked RadioButton Index using jQuery? I need to read it and save to cookies to load status later using code

```
$('input[name="compression"]')[{Reading from cookies code}].checked = true;



1<input name="compression" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />
2<input name="compression" type="radio" value="2" />
3<input name="compression" type="radio" value="3" />
```

Regards
Tomas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This returns the zero-based index of the selected radiobutton

```
$('input[name=compression]:checked').index()
```

For the case described in the comment use (which generally is the right syntax to use)

```
$('input[name=porient]:checked').index('input[name=porient]')
```

If you want to know why the first one gives wrong results you should read the [.index() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If no argument is passed to the
>   .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of
>   the first element within the jQuery
>   object relative to its sibling
>   elements.

In the sample from the question there weren't any "other" siblings but your radiobuttons. Thus it works.

In the sample from the comment the `<br />` tag is a sibling of the radiobuttons and thus is on index 1. That's why you think `index()` gives the wrong position

Comment: Strange thing, it works fine on "compression" radio buttons which code listed above, but on code below for "porient" radio buttons it return wrong indexes. If first radio button selected, it return 0 (ok) it second selected it return 2(!!!!) Can't understand what is going on. Any ideas?

            <p>
                <input name="porient" type="radio" value="portrait" checked="checked" />Portrait
                <br />
                <input name="porient" type="radio" value="landscape" />Landscape
            </p>